# HgScc tutorial?

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial

Does anyone know of a tutorial or guide for HgScc (Mercurial)?

I've installed and integrated HgScc with VS2010, but having never used any source control other than TFS, I'm not all that sure what I'm doing.

For instance, I've committed more than one version of a file but Revert is still greyed-out in the context menu. And how do I assign Beyond Compare as the Diff tool?

I can find plenty of people discussing and recommending it but I can't find any guide on how to use it.

[It's not a Mercurial tutorial I'm looking for as I don't intend to use the command line.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set diff tool for HgSccPackage in the MS Visual Studio settings:

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Mercurial Options Page -> Diff Tool

In 1.8.5 it has moved to:

Mercurial -> Options -> Diff tools

Answer (score 0):

I believe HgSCC uses the configuration settings of Mercurial, so you need to go through the [.hg\hgrc documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) for the Beyond Compare setting.
And to get what happens when you commit you will need to look at the philosophy of Mercurial and other DVCS's. So [HGInit](http://www.hginit.com) is still a good source of getting to know HgSCC.